# How to insert single existing pair into a map

Tags: c++, insert, stdmap, std-pair

I have an already defined `pair`, and I want to `insert` it into a `map`. What are the correct way/s of doing that?

I tried two. One works. The other (which I mean to use, since it is more compact and clear) does not. There are no runtime errors, but it simply does not work (I checked this with the return value of `insert`, whose second member is `False`).
I guess the way to fix the second form is simple, but I could not find it.

This is what I have:

```
using namespace std;
typedef pair<string, char> pair_t;
typedef map<pair_t::first_type, pair_t::second_type> map_t;
typedef pair<map_t::iterator,bool> retval_insert_t;

int main(void) {
    pair_t p2;
    p2 = make_pair("Fer", 'C');

    map_t grade_list;
    grade_list[ "Jorge" ] = 'A';
    grade_list.insert(make_pair("Alba", 'D'));
    grade_list.insert(pair_t("Susi", 'C'));
    grade_list.insert(make_pair(p2.first, p2.second));  //  This works
    grade_list.insert(p2);                              //  This does not work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the second form doesn't work when the first one is enabled too? In other words, if you comment out the first form, does the second form work?

Comment: The latter can't insert because the former already did. `"Fer"` is already keyed in the map after the prior `make_pair` insertion. Are you expecting the behavior of a `std::multimap` ?

Comment: @Leon - Bingo, that was it. At one point I was checking behavior the right way (with no two attempts at inserting the same key), and there was something wrong. I do not have that code though, so I wouldn't know what the problem was. Later, I obviously fixed it, but I introduced the "multiple attempts". Thanks. You may post this as an answer.